# Cómo crear listas desplegables dependientes usando PHP con la misma tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, php7, html-select

soy nuevo en esto y agradezco que me ayuden en un dilema que tengo.

necesito hacer una lista  donde al seleccionar una opción , se desplegué una segunda lista dependiente de lo que haya seleccionado en la primera y así hasta una tercera vez. La idea es poder seleccionar, una serie las temporadas que tiene esa serie y por ultimo los capítulos de esa temporada. El problema es que diseñe una tabla en MYSQL donde toda esa información está disponible en la misma tabla y todos los tutoriales que he podido encontrar ocupan diferentes tablas que las relacionan.

el código que tengo es este.

```
<?php

session_start();
if (empty ($_SESSION["id"])) {
header('location:../login/login.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../generos/css/bootstrap.min (1).css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/descripcion.css">
    <div class="encabezado">
    <label class="encabezado"> Acción </label>
   </div>
</head>
<div class="container">
<div class="mb-2" >
                <label class="form-label">mira las series que ya existente</label>
            <?php
include '../../modelo/bd_accion.php';
$conexion=conexion();
                    $query=temporadaS($conexion);      
?>
            <select name="serie" id="serie">
                <?php
                while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['serie']?>"> <?php echo $datos['serie']?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>          
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-2" >
                <label class="form-label">mira las temporadas que ya existente en la serie seleccionada</label>
            <?php
$conexion=conexion();
                    $query=temporada($conexion);      
?>
            <select name="temporadas">
                <?php
                while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['temporada']?>"> <?php echo $datos['temporada']?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>          
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-2" >
                <label class="form-label">mira los capitulos  que existente en la temporada seleccionada</label>
                 <?php
                    $conexion=conexion();
                    $query=temporadaC($conexion);      
                    ?>
            <select name="capitulos">
                <?php
                while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['capitulo']?>"> <?php echo $datos['capitulo']?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>          
            </select>
            </div>



Y ESTA ES EL CODIGO DE MI BASE DE DATOS:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-ua-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-dive-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>conexion mysql</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<?php 

function conexion(){
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','series');
    return $con;
}


function Temporada($conexion){
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT temporada FROM accion_s   ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    return $query;
}

function TemporadaC($conexion){
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT capitulo FROM accion_s ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    return $query;
}

function TemporadaS($conexion){
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT serie  FROM accion_s ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    return $query;
}
function TemporadaID($conexion){
    $sql="SELECT id  FROM accion_s ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    return $query;
}

?>

</body>
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola bienvenido. Entiendo que hay métodos con CSS y JavaScript. Usando listeners a eventos click despliegas y repliegas u ocultas contenedores **div**. ¿O el asunto es solo en la organización de la tabla de series?

Comment: Hola, puedo plegar y replegar los <select> sin problemas, incluso puedo acceder a la tabla con la información sin problemas. el único paso que no he podido lograr es filtrar el resultado de la información a mostrar en el segundo y tercer <select>, dependiendo de que fue lo que se seleccionó previamente. he pensado en utilizar if y else. pero no tengo muy claro como redactar la orden para eso. Saludos

Comment: A ver, en pasos: #1 el usuario recibe la página con las opciones en <SELECT> y las va seleccionado hasta obtener la que busca descargar/ver. #2 cuando selecciona; se hace un submit y, mediante JS envías el contenido de las selecciones, a un PHP, sea por sus ids o por sus contenidos textuales, o ambos. #3 en Server tomas todo, lo filtras y buscas en BD lo solicitado. #4 en Server organizas todo, y envías; sea el contenido binario o URL para descargar. ¿En cuál paso es el problema con el filtrado? Me interesa porque también quiero montar una red local para proveer contenido a clientes y vecinos

Comment: el problema está en el filtrado, como tengo en la bd más de una temporada y capítulos por series,  use "SELECT DISTINCT serie  FROM accion_s" para que no se repitan los nombres al momento de seleccionar en el primer <SELECT> hasta acá todo bien, pero lo que necesito es que si seleccionan una serie, el  siguiente <SELECT> me muestre las temporadas que existen de esa serie en particular.   se me ocurrió agregar el ID a la primera selección para poder apoyarme en eso para buscar en la bd la información para el siguiente  <SELECT> pero como son distintos ID no discrimina la orden DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente me parece un problema de organización, si no me equivoco, porque ciertamente no puedes usar los id de la tabla, ya que tienes un montón de series distintas.

Los tutoriales que indicas hacen uso de

> claves foráneas

Yo lo organizaría como lo hiciste; en una tabla, pero debajo de id añadiría otro campo que funcione como "id" de cada clase de serie, mas un campo para temporada; número de capítulo etcétera. Sin importar el "id" de registro en tabla.

Quedaría así:
Orden de la tabla **accion_s**:

```
id=1, genero='Serie India', nombre='Dubai 2023', capitulos='1 - 30', url='la URL de descarga'
```

Entonces:

```
SELECT url FROM accion_s WHERE genero='Serie India' AND nombre='Dubai 2023' AND capitulos='1 - 30';
```

**Mismos datos que tienes que recibir del usuario cuando termine de seleccionar.**

Y si cambia la selección, no hay problema, recibirá la url correspondiente. Pero tendrás que hacer una reorganización tremenda en tu base de datos. Puedes tener cualquier cantidad de paquetes de video, encontrarás todo. Igual que como lo organizamos en un papel.

**Hacerlo ahora te ayudará mucho en el futuro de tu negocio; ahorrar trabajo y tiempo.**

Espero haberte ayudado, realmente me interesa este tema.

**Actualización**

Añadiendo más datos de tu misma pregunta, veo que se le pueden hacer unas mejoras extra a tu código. Puedes "reciclar" tu función de conexiones, aunque ésto también se puede hacer mejor:

Aquí no se necesita HTML, creo:
bd_accion.php

```
// A ésta le darás lo que deseas buscar
function Temporada( $T_C_S_id ){
    // Preparar nueva conexión cada vez
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '****', 'series');
    
    // Variable para consulta final
    $sql = '';
    
    // Opciones ...
    switch ( $T_C_S_id ) {
        case "temporada":  // de Temporada
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT temporada FROM accion_s ";
            break;
        
        case "capitulo":  // de TemporadaC
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT capitulo FROM accion_s ";
            break;
        
        case "serie":  // de TemporadaS
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT serie FROM accion_s ";
            break;
        
        case "id":  // de TemporadaID
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM accion_s ";
            break;
        
        /*default:
            "Valor Default";*/
    }
    
    // Ejecutar consulta $sql mediante $con
    // Recordar siempre evitar inyección SQL
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
    // y devolver los resultados
    return $query;
}
```

Ahora **series.php**:
(Con unos ajustes. Lo iré mejorando más adelante')

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty ($_SESSION["id"])) {
        header('Location:../login/login.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <title> Documento de selección </title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min (1).css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/descripcion.css">
        
    </head>
        
        <div class="encabezado">
            <label class="encabezado"> Acción </label>
        </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-2" >
            <label class="form-label">Mira las series ya existentes</label>
            
            <?php
            include 'bd_accion.php';
            
            // Pasar cadena "serie" como parámetro
            $query=Temporada( 'serie' );
            ?>
            
            <select name="serie" id="serie">
                <?php
                    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $datos['serie']?>">
                    <?php echo $datos['serie']?>
                </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-2" >
            <label class="form-label">
                Mira las temporadas ya existentes en la serie seleccionada
            </label>
            
            <?php
                // Pasar cadena "temporada" como parámetro
                $query=Temporada( 'temporada' );
            ?>
            <select name="temporadas">
                <?php
                    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $datos['temporada']?>">
                    <?php echo $datos['temporada']?>
                </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-2" >
            <label class="form-label">
                Mira los capítulos existentes en la temporada seleccionada
            </label>
            
            <?php
                // Pasar cadena "capitulo" como parámetro
                $query=Temporada( 'capitulo' );
            ?>
            <select name="capitulos">
                <?php
                    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $datos['capitulo']?>">
                    <?php echo $datos['capitulo']?>
                </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Revisa a ver si lo vez mejor así. (11:40 pm)

Comment: gracias, lo intentare como dices y te cuento como me fue